# opening .xcworkspace file, shows up as a framework in Xcode recents instead of a workspace

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

normally, when opening an `xcworkspace` file, it shows up normally in Xcode recents

this is the `xcworkspace` location
[image: folder structure]

and this is how it shows up in recents
[image: recents]

how to make it show up as a workspace in recents instead?

Disclaimer: I know I can go to the folder and open the file, this normally works, but why it shows up incorrectly in recents?

Comment: You have Package.swift in the folder.

Comment: so, this counts as a feature, and it should not be solved in the first place?

Comment: but, shouldn't opening the workspace override the presence of Package.swift ?

Comment: The fact that this has yet to be solved is one of the reasons I won't switch to SPM. And I am absolutely amazed there's nothing on this subject anywhere. This SO question is the only one I can find complaining about this.